# Use our chat room!

Tags: support

The *comment* feature is very useful to request *clarifications* on questions and answers with the goal of improving the quality and value of the commented question or answer. It's less useful for *discussions* that drift away from the actual question or answer - that's what the site's chat room is for.

**Few new users realize how awesome the chat is**; it has many neat features you're not used to from other chat systems you grew up with! You can even chat with people who are not even online, so you don't have to be in the room yourself for very long. They'll be notified the next time they visit any page in the Stack Exchange network.

**--> Check out the [chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) to get started, then [visit our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting)!**

If you need help with the chat system, you can simply post a question in the chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the "get a room" feature is now deployed, and will funnel extended comment discussions to chat automatically.

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/can-we-get-a-simple-way-to-initiate-a-chat/1766#1766

(or at least it will strongly urge people to..)

Comment: Jeff, how do I get this to work? I want to apply this to http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4241/how-can-i-get-my-toddler-to-exit-discreetly-when-threatening-looking-people-are/4246#comment6485_4246, which has gone bonkers bananas, and the option isn't available.

Comment: @deworde: The "please avoid discussions" thing only appears when *two* people comment back and forth. Also see these related feature requests: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat