# Why are the site moderators editing all the questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, moderators, site-promotion

*Some users might notice that nearly all questions have been edited to some extent recently. This meta question exists to explain what is going on.*

Stack Exchange (the company who is hosting our site) is actively working to raise the readability of the content. That's a good thing because it generates better Google search results. One of the ways to raise the quality is to edit the questions' titles to be expressed as a question, the way I would phrase it if I were talking to you. Two *parenting* site moderators heard of this and offered to help with that effort. This is why Beofett and TorbenGB appear to have edited so many questions.

Please note that the edits are done by hand, with a careful eye toward keeping the meaning intact. We change the wording of the question's title, check if the tags are good, and sometimes clean up the formatting a little bit. That is all.

If we make a change to a question title and you don't happen to like it, or you felt it was better the way it was before, feel free to revert the question to a previous version of the question -- no harm, no foul.

If you'd like to know more, [this meta question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/who-is-aarthi-devanathan-and-why-is-she-changing-so-many-posts) explains it even better, and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character/100359#100359) puts a face on the staff. You can also [talk to us in the parenting chat](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/use-our-chat-room).

Parenting isn't a part of the CHAOS program (yet), but we felt that it would be beneficial to be proactive and bring our content in line with the program before it becomes a much larger task, while also taking advantage of the opportunity to catch up with some of the older content we may have missed.

Comment: It's a shame that this makes the RSS feed of "recent questions" rather worthless.  Hopefully this is over soon.

Comment: @Tony, the work is finished now. We apologize for flooding the RSS feed, but we had no other means. We may of course edit future questions as they arrive, but this bulk change shouldn't repeat itself soon.

Comment: Refering to the "mods" as "site moderators" would improve readability and also make it climb in Google search results. Also, most of what's written as part of the question should be posted as an answer instead

Comment: @David I've changed the post title. (I think you have the same permissions?)

Answer (score 7):

Nice work! It's easy to become so accustom to reading unspecific, poorly-phrased titles... Seeing the results of your efforts reminds me of why I first signed on to Stack Exchange: a set of clean, descriptive, well-written titles is soothing and inviting.